# Connect Ruby Gem to Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm modifying a Ruby Gem to allow it to modify a Rails database via a rake task.

I was able to connect the database and modify its content by passing the database configuration as parameters to the rake task, which then called the `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`. My question is, how could the Gem connect to the Rails database without having to specify the database configuration as parameters in the rake task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the gem has access to the `Rails.application`, you can access the database config file with

```rb
db_config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
```

If it doesn't, you can parse the file yourself.

```rb
db_config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read('./config/database.yml')).result)
```

Once you have your configuration, you can pass it into the connector.

Comment: My gem has access to `Rails.application` and the first line works well, thank you!